# AWS suported R studio - Error installing Rattle library

Tags: r, amazon-ec2, redhat

I am using AWS environment supported R studio .

I tried to install package ("rattle").

I am getting below error

```
> * installing *source* package ‘RGtk2’ ...
> ** package ‘RGtk2’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config checking pkg-config is at least
> version 0.9.0... yes checking for INTROSPECTION... no checking for
> GTK... no configure: error: GTK version 2.8.0 required ERROR:
> configuration failed for package ‘RGtk2’
> * removing ‘/home/ui/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4/RGtk2’ Warning
> in install.packages :   installation of package ‘RGtk2’ had non-zero
> exit status
> * installing *source* package ‘cairoDevice’ ...
> ** package ‘cairoDevice’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked checking for pkg-config... pkg-config ERROR: gtk+2.0 not found by
> pkg-config. ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘cairoDevice’
> * removing ‘/home/uids7592/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4/cairoDevice’
> Warning in install.packages :   installation of package ‘cairoDevice’
> had non-zero exit status ERROR: dependencies ‘RGtk2’, ‘cairoDevice’
> are not available for package ‘rattle’
> * removing ‘/home/uids7592/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4/rattle’ Warning
> in install.packages :   installation of package ‘rattle’ had non-zero
> exit status
> 
> The downloaded source packages are in
>   ‘/tmp/Rtmpiq3Gxf/downloaded_packages’
```

Comment: Been there! you need to manually install `GTK`

Comment: something like sudo yum install GTK ?

Comment: yeah try that. There is good information available about this. Also make sure you install the right version.

Comment: Focus  on checking for
 `GTK... no configure: error: GTK version 2.8.0 required ERROR:`

Comment: @RanaUsman yeah will try to